# How to get json data from Kendo UI treeview select event

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview, kendo-datasource

I have retrieving the data from json for treeview. When i select the treeview, it will show the data which is belong from same json. How to get the data from json

```
 console.log("select",k.node)
```

This is used for get the data for selected node. But I want the data from JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most widgets have a [`dataItem`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/treeview#methods-dataItem) method which gives you the corresponding data item in the data source:

```
var item = e.sender.dataItem(e.node);
```

Answer (score 2):

You might do:

```
var item = this.dataItem(k.node);
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/jtgfjz8w/1/